# Junit: Testing If-clause in method

Tags: java, junit

For my application I have a function `handler` like that:

```
class MyFoo {

    private MyFoo2 myFoo2 = new MyFoo2();

    public void handler(Object o) {

        if (o.getName().equals("Name1")) {
            myFoo2.doSomeStuff1(o);
        } else if (o.getName().equals("Name2")) {
            myFoo2.doSomeStuff2(o);
        }
    }
}

class MyFoo2{

    List<Object> objectList=new ArrayList<>();

    public void doSomeStuff1(Object o){
        //prepare Object o I
        objectList.add(o);
    }

    public void doSomeStuff2(Object o){
        //prepare Object o II
        objectList.add(o);
    }

    public getObjectList(){
        return objectList;
    }
}
```

Now I want to test my function `handler` with JUnit. To test it, should i have to get the `objectList` from my `MyFoo2` and check the entry or is there another way to check a function like that? 
What is here a good way for testing? 
Are test like that unnecessary?

Comment: Note: Comparing strings with `==` does not do what you think it does in Java. See: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @Jesper: Thanks for that hint

Comment: Side note: if you are interested in learning stuff ... consider getting rid of such if statements. Actually, in good OO designs, you dont do "if" ... but you use polymorphism. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc&list=PLD0011D00849E1B79&index=4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you ara talking about unit test, the correct way to test is should be without `MyFoo2`

You are testing `MyFoo1`, so you can mock `MyFoo2` and use it just to verify the execution happens. something like:

```
public class MyFoo1Test {

  @Mock private MyFoo2 mockMyFoo2;

  @InjectMocks
  private MyFoo1 myFoo1 = new MyFoo1();

  @Test
  public void testHandlerName1() {
    Object o = new Object("Name1"); 
    myFoo1.handler(o);
    verify(myFoo2).doSomeStuff1(o);
  }

  @Test
  public void testHandlerName2() {
    Object o = new Object("Name2"); 
    myFoo1.handler(o);
    verify(myFoo2).doSomeStuff2(o);
  }

  @Test
  public void testHandlerOtherName() {
    Object o = new Object("OtherName"); 
    myFoo1.handler(o);
    verifyZeroInteractions(myFoo2);
  }

}
```

Unit tests for `MyFoo2` should be done seperatly, and in there you should test the `doSomeStuff` methods

Comment: In your implementation, the myFoo2  mock  is not associated to the myFoo1.
So the mock cannot work.
Besides, why coupling the question to a specific mocking implementation ? Here mockito.

Comment: It 's I said. This code cannot work. You must associate the MyFoo2  instance to  the MyFoo1 instance. You can use constructor, setter, or reflections...

Answer (score 2):

In your case, if I would do a "real" unit test, i would isolate myFoo2 instance by injecting a mock inside and in my JUnit assertion, i would assert that  myFoo2.doSomeStuff1(o) is called when the good o.getName() is present.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer lies in your question itself :

```
Should i have to get the objectList from my MyFoo2 and check the entry?
```

Does that mean you need to test the method `doSomeStuff1` of your `MyFoo2` class in it's own unit test?

Well yes, you create unit test for your class `MyFoo2` and perform all tests related to that class in it's own unit test class, rather than testing it as part of some another test class.

**UPDATE :**

When unit testing your `handler` method, you should only test that it calls appropriate methods on `myFoo2` object (`doSomeStuff1` or `doSomeStuff2`) depending on test. You could use mocking util like mockito for `myFoo2` and verify that `doSomeStuff1` or `doSomeStuff1` is called on that mock object.

Comment: I know  I have to check `doSomeStuff1 ` in a extra Unit-Test.  But I want to check `handler ` also or is it unnecessary?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Do add unit test case for the handler method also. To ensure the if-else conditions are covered.

Also adding to the comment by Jesper, 
 1) always do a null pointer check before getting values from an object during comparison 
or 
 2) just move that to right side of the comparison .

Ex.: "Name1".equals(o.getName())

Please consider this as comment since I don't yet have access to provide comments